# Inserting state into a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This seems like a simple one but it's causing me issues. I want to take state and pass it into a string/property that I'm using with chartjs.

This piece of code works fine.

```
render() {
        const data = {
            labels: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Label1',
                    fill: false,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    data: this.props.historicalData[this.state.time].catB.myitem.data,
                },
```

What I want to change is 'myitem' to be whatever is in my state (which is being changed on click of buttons).

I've tried:

```
data: this.props.historicalData[this.state.time].catB.this.state.myItem.data,
```

and also

```
data: `this.props.historicalData[this.state.time].catB.{this.state.myItem}.data`,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data: this.props.historicalData[this.state.time].catB[this.state.myItem].data,
```

Comment: I tried that also but it returns Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: Sorry - it does work if I remove the period after catB which I hadn't tried. thank you!